# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0,

Tags: c#, .net-5

I have a console application on net 5.0.
I'm trying to load assembly at runtime:

```
Assembly loadedAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
var controllers = loadedAssembly.GetExportedTypes();
```

Method `GetExportedTypes` throws this exception

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot
> find the file specified.

I don't have such library in any of my project files. Assembly also has target framework 5.0

Can't find similar error by search in internet. What it can be?

Comment: Check web.config for auto generated assembly version binding. Check if Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstraction is there. Correct its version to your system assembly version.

Comment: Hi what are you trying to load? It's a your dll or an external once?

Comment: @StefanoCavion, my dll

Comment: @ziakhan, found only
`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />`
not 5.0.0.0

Comment: Run this from nuget package console PM> Get-Project –All | Add-BindingRedirect

Comment: @ziakhan no, please don't suggest to add bindingredirect. the existence of PackageReference means bindingredirect is not necessary.

Comment: @ziakhan, I ran binding in my assemly, published it to folder and then tried to load from published directory. The same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/4187907/net-picking-wrong-referenced-assembly-version   please refer to it.

Comment: Found in deps.json 
` "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.Reference": "5.0.0.0"`

Why it was generated? I think, it is a mistake

Comment: I added 
   <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
to my main application.

Now it works, no errors

Comment: I have the same issue with .NET 6. I'm trying to load project which is using the "Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Web" SDK. That's why there is no assembly after publish.  Is your application using it or any of its dependencies?

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson, ready

Answer (score 2):

Add

`<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`

to the erroring projects csproj or vbproj file and the error will disappear.

Edit:

The error can occur with v6 DLLs as well:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0

The solution is to remove the PackageReference and replace it with the FrameworkReference.